# How to update my App Inventor/ Thunkable app with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, app-inventor

I am trying to rewrite my app from App Inventor in Android Studio, I copied the package name and keystore to Android Studio and downloaded my app update, but it won't install. it just says app not installed. Is there anything else I should have done to make the update compatible?

Comment: see [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mitappinventortest/WWQVvqm7ONc/4wdAfDv0AgAJ) in the App Inventor forum or do a search there

Comment: **logcat** might tell you why it won't install...